# Visual Studio exits on assertion failure with no error message

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I have a very similar problem to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7416620/1397061), but with a single-threaded C++ program: when an assertion fails during debugging in Visual Studio 2013, the debugger exits immediately without showing the assertion failure message box, which is supposed to look something like this:

[image]

(This picture is not from my own code.)

The only error message is:

```
The program '[5156] myprogram.exe' has exited with code 3 (0x3).
```

which makes it nearly impossible to figure out where the assertion failure occurred since the code base is very large.

The response to the linked question suggested adding a call to:

```
_CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_ASSERT, _CRTDBG_MODE_DEBUG);
```

at the beginning of the program, so that the assertion error is at least printed to the output window.  However, this is not only hacky, but also not necessary for any other program I have debugged in Visual Studio.

This is not my own Visual Studio project, and I'm wondering if there is a rogue setting somewhere.  I have enabled "Break when an exception is thrown" for assertion errors in Debug -> Exceptions, so that is not the issue.

How can I force the "Debug Assertion Failed!" message box to appear when an assertion fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, the problem was that Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library was set to "Multi-threaded" for both the Debug and Release builds.  The correct setting is "Multi-threaded Debug" for the Debug build and "Multi-threaded" for the Release Build.

Comment: It's set to Multi-threaded Debug in my project, but I still don't get any assertion windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can try set a custom invalid_parameter_handler.

I encounter a similar problem when using vs2017.

the following code will not trigger debug assertion fail notice when i use my vs2017 to debug.

```cpp
char dst[128] = { 0 };
char src[256] = { 0 };
memcpy_s(dst, sizeof(dst), src, sizeof(src));
```

but when i set a custom handler. it works. Checkout this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/set-invalid-parameter-handler-set-thread-local-invalid-parameter-handler?view=vs-2019)